# Mustache php space in templates

Tags: javascript, php, templates, mustache, mustache.php

I have this template code:

```
{{#album}}
<h1>{{ hinfo.artist_name }}</h1>
<h2>{{ hinfo.name }}</h2>
{{/album}}
```

which renders:

```
<h1></h1><h2></h2>
```

Instead if I write:

```
{{#album}}
<h1>{{hinfo.artist_name}}</h1>
<h2>{{hinfo.name}}</h2>    
{{/album}}
```

it succesfully shows:

```
<h1>my artist</h1><h2>my album name</h2>
```

In the [javascript version](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) of the same library, this behaviour with blank spaces is not happening. I added a function helper in the php constructor:

```
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine( 
    array( 
        'loader' => new Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader( 
            self::$_dir, 
            array('extension' => '.mst') 
        ),
        /*
        'helpers' => array(
            'fn' => function($text, $render) {
                        $parsed = $render($text);
                        $date = date("F j, Y  h:i", (int) $parsed);
                        return $date;
                    }
        )*/
    )
);
```

but is not being executed in this example.

Could anyone tell me if this behavior is correct or is a bug in the [mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) 2.10 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything appears to be working as expect. I'm not sure *exactly* what your issue is.

In Mustache.php, `{{hinfo.artist_name}}` (no spaces) is correct syntax.

In Mustache.js, `{{ hinfo.artist_name }}` (*with* spaces) is correct syntax.

Comment: The issue is that it seems to be a non documented incompatibility, if it's as you say. Thankfully the notation in js `{{hinfo.name}}` is working as well which removes the kaos of duplicating the templates just for a space issue, *in case your project use the templates both from client and server side logic*.

Answer (score 0):

Mustache.php supports all tag names with or without spaces at the start and end. For example, this does exactly what you'd expect:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$m = new Mustache_Engine();

$tpl = <<<EOS
{{#album}}
<h1>{{ hinfo.artist_name }}</h1>
<h2>{{ hinfo.name }}</h2>
{{/album}}
EOS;

$tpl2 = <<<EOS
{{# album }}
<h1>{{ hinfo.artist_name }}</h1>
<h2>{{ hinfo.name }}</h2>
{{/ album }}
EOS;

$data = [
  'album' => [
    'hinfo' => [
      'artist_name' => 'my artist',
      'name' => 'my album name',
    ]
  ]
];

echo $m->render($tpl, $data);
echo $m->render($tpl2, $data);

assert($m->render($tpl, $data) === $m->render($tpl2, $data));
```

The output of the two templates is identical.

If this isn't what you're seeing, please provide a full test case and we might be able to track it down :)